# VBO doesn't use UV coordinates

Tags: opengl, opengl-es-2.0

My render method currently looks like this:

```
void Renderer::render() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    checkGlError("glClear");

    EntityCamera* camera = (EntityCamera*) resourceManager_->getResource(GHOST_CAMERA);

    mat4 proj;
    Matrix::projection3D(proj, 45.0f,
            (float) nScreenWidth_ / nScreenHeight_, GHOST_NEAR_DISTANCE, GHOST_FAR_DISTANCE);

    mat4 view;
    Matrix::multiply(proj, camera_->getMatrix(), view);
    camera->extractPlanes(view);

    for (vector<Node*>::const_iterator it = renderArray_.begin(); it != renderArray_.end();
            it++) {
        Node* node = *it;
        if (!node->isRenderable()) {
            continue;
        }
        if (node->hasBV() && node->getBV()->isInFrustum(camera, node) == BoundingVolume::OUTSIDE) {
            LOGI("Node %s is outside :O", node->getName().c_str());
            continue;
        }
        EntityModel* entity =
                static_cast<EntityModel*>(resourceManager_->getResource(
                        (*it)->getEntity()));
        if (entity == 0 || entity->getVertices() == 0 || entity->getVertices()->size() == 0) {
            LOGI("Empty entity %s.", node->getName().c_str());
            continue;
        }
        Resource* resource = resourceManager_->getResource(node->getShader());
        Shader* shader = static_cast<Shader*>(resource);
        Resource* resource2 = resourceManager_->getResource(entity->getTexture());
        Image* image = static_cast<Image*>(resource2);
        mat4 res;
        Matrix::multiply(view, node->getMatrix(), res);

        // Select shader program to use.
        glUseProgram(shader->getId());
        checkGlError("glUseProgram");

        int matrix = glGetUniformLocation(shader->getId(), "uWVP");
        int texture = glGetUniformLocation(shader->getId(), "texture_0");
        checkGlError("glGetUniformLocation");
        int textureCoords = glGetAttribLocation(shader->getId(), "attrTexCoords");
        int vertices = glGetAttribLocation(shader->getId(), "attrPos");
        checkGlError("glGetAttribLocation");

        // Specify WVP matrix.
        glUniformMatrix4fv(matrix, 1, false, res);
        checkGlError("glUniformMatrix4fv");

        // Load vertex positions.
        if (!entity->isCompiled()) {
            //LOGI("Entity %s, not compiled.", entity->getName().c_str());
            continue;
        }
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(vertices);
        checkGlError("glEnableVertexAttribArray");
        //glVertexAttribPointer(vertices, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0,
        //      &(*entity->getVertices())[0]);
        //LOGI("%s vbo id: %d", node->getName().c_str(), entity->getVBO());
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, entity->getVBO());
        checkGlError("glBindBuffer");
        glVertexAttribPointer(vertices, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
        checkGlError("glVertexAttribPointer");
        // Load UV coordinates.
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(textureCoords);
        checkGlError("glEnableVertexAttribArray");
        glVertexAttribPointer(textureCoords, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0,
                &(*entity->getTextureCoords())[0]);
        checkGlError("glVertexAttribPointer");

        // Bind the texture.
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        checkGlError("glActiveTexture");
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, image->getId());
        checkGlError("glBindTexture");
        glUniform1i(texture, 0);
        checkGlError("glUniform1i");

        if (entity->hasIndices()) {
            vector<vector<GLushort>*>* indices = entity->getIndices();
            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < indices->size(); i++) {
                if (entity->hasBoundingVolumes()) {
                    BoundingVolume* volume = (*entity->getBoundingVolumes())[i];
                    if (volume->isInFrustum(camera, node) == BoundingVolume::OUTSIDE) {
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                vector<GLushort>* ind = (*indices)[i];
                glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, ind->size(), GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, &(*ind)[0]);
                checkGlError("glDrawElements");
            }
        }
        else {
            glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, entity->getVertices()->size() / 3);
            checkGlError("glDrawArrays");
        }
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        checkGlError("glBindBuffer");
    }
}
```

---

I just recently tried to use VBO, before I was sending vertex data directly and everything worked fine, textures were mapped correctly. Now I changed vertex array with VBO and even though it works, no textures are applied, I could only see black object.

---

1. What might be wrong with my textures?
2. Why when I change glVertexAttribPointer(vertices, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0); line order with glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, entity->getVBO()); I get disfigured objects? Is this the right call order that I'm using?

Comment: I didn't wade through your code yet, but the general oder of opeations is 1. bind object 2. set object parameters 3. load data into object. Steps 2 and 3 are interchangable by specification, but the given order triggers less driver bugs. Not that active units (like texture units or simiar) go even before the bind. So for textures first set the active unit, then bind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're sending your UV coordinates from plain memory, while you seem to send your vertex coordinates from a VBO. This may not be so efficient, you should have both data sets in VBO to profit of the VBO advantages.

That being said, I think your problem is that you don't unbind your VBO before sending your UV coordinates. Your code should be :

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glVertexAttribPointer(textureCoords, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0,
            &(*entity->getTextureCoords())[0]);
```

as I suppose your `getTextureCoords()` does not return an offset in your VBO.

Comment: This was indeed the case of unbinding, and now it works. Yes, I plan to add texture coordinates to same VBO later, I just wanted to do this in a few steps so I could get a better understanding of how this works. Thank you.